# Make a video be visible only through the shape of an SVG file?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is it possible to have an SVG file on top of a div with a fullscreen video, and let the video be visible only through the shape of the SVG file? (See the attached image for better understanding).

[image]

Comment: Look at the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114703/how-do-i-draw-a-shape-on-an-html5-video-using-svg
Does it helps you?

Comment: Unfortunately. That only showed how to draw SVG on top of a video.

Comment: Exactly as I mean. Set an opaque SVG shape with some holes over the video.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't make it work. Could you please sketch up a fast codepen.io with an example?

Comment: I haven't enough time, sorry. Try to reproduce the accepted solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for trying to get me on the right track though!